# Как программно поменять стартовое Activity в Java под Андроид?

Tags: java, android, activity

Всем привет. Изучаю Java под Андроид в среде android studio и у меня возник вопрос: Как программно поменять стартовое Activity? К примеру, есть стартовое активити "А" с выбором активити "В" и "С", я хочу чтобы в активити "setting" был switch - "не показывать стартовое активити" и тогда? при следующем запуске, грузилось заданное активити, либо пункты с выбором стартового активити.

Я уже что только не пробовал, весь интернет перерыл и не нашел ничего похожего. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Просто сохраните переменную, в которой будете хранить нужный параметр для условия запускаемой активности
А при старте splashscreen или запуске первой активности в методе onCreate пропишите условия перехода к нужной активности.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого в манифесте (AndroidManifest.xml) нужно в нужной вам активности добавить фильтр:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

а в той которая сейчас стартует по-умолчанию убрать эти строки, должно быть по итогу так:

```
<activity
android:name="активность"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

и у вас будет стартоваться заданная вами активность. Но не забудьте проверить чтобы такой фильтр был в одном экземпляре, потому что получится так что у вас будет две иконки приложения, и вы сможете запустить приложение с двух активностей :)